# I need to implement OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Flow for Server-to-Server Integration using a community user

Tags: jwt, salesforce, salesforce-communities

I need to be able to get the access token using JWT for community users. My end goal is to use this access token to use it with frontdoor.jsp

This is my request:

```
 curl --location --request POST 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cookie: BrowserId=P8QALYKvEeyLlh_jJBTAjg; CookieConsentPolicy=0:0; LSKey-c$CookieConsentPolicy=0:0' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer' \
--data-urlencode 'assertion=my-jwt'
```

This is the payload for my JWT:

```
{
"iss" : <connected-app-consumer-key>,
"sub" : "someCommunityUser@gmail.com",
"aud" : "https://my-community.force.com/customers",
"exp" : "1654818853"
}
```

and I'm getting this error:

[Postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3WcE.png)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing is because the token endpoint you are using is for internal users. If you want to authenticate an experience user (community user) you need to use a different token endpoint, not the https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token.

The token endpoint should look like this

https://your-custom-domain.eu27.force.com/partners/services/oauth2/token

- your-experiece-domain.eu27.force.com is the domain assigned for your experience site if you didn't set up a custom one.
- partners is the path of your experience site, if any
- /service/oauth2/token is the classic endpoint to get access tokens

After this you can continue getting an "user hasn't approved this consumer", if so

1. Go to your Connected App -> Manage -> Edit Policies
2. Set Permitted Users to "Admin approved users are pre-authorized"
3. Click Save
4. Scroll down to "Profiles" or "Permission Sets"
5. Click "Manage Profiles" or "Manage Permission Sets"
6. Add the Profile of the partners users you want to be pre-authorized or the Permission Set your want use to grant access to the experience site.

Hope this helps!